# Separating two numeric characters from among several characters between two columns

Tags: sql-server, database-design

how Separating two numeric characters from among several characters between two columns and subtracting those two numbers separated from each other in SQL according to the figure
[image]

```
sys3.fn_DateToShamsiDate(dd.BirthDate) as "1",
sys3.fn_DateToShamsiDate(getdate()) as "2",
SUBSTRING(sys3.fn_DateToShamsiDate(getdate()),4,2) as "3",    
 SUBSTRING(sys3.fn_DateToShamsiDate(dd.BirthDate),4,2) as "4" ,

SUBSTRING(sys3.fn_DateToShamsiDate(getdate()),4,2) -SUBSTRING(sys3.fn_DateToShamsiDate(dd.BirthDate),4,2) as "5",
```

Comment: Please always tag which database system and version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just trying to count the difference between *only* the months of two dates. Assuming the actual columns / data points are true dates, you can simply do the following:

```
SELECT MONTH(GETDATE()) - MONTH(dd.BirthDate) AS RawMonthDifference;
```

But this seems like a meaningless data point.

Perhaps you actually want the number of months between the entire dates themselves (aka how much time has passed, in months). To do so, you could use `DATEDIFF()` instead, like so:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, GETDATE(), dd.BirthDate) AS ActualMonthDifference;
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, due to the solar date(solar calendar), it is not possible to use date difference functions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOYrb.jpg